# How to get string of everything between these two em tag?

Tags: regex, coldfusion, html-parsing, coldfusion-8

I want to get string between em tag , including other html also.

for example:

```
<em>UNIVERSALPOSTAL UNION - International Bureau Circular<br />
By: K.J.S. McKeown</em>
```

output should be as:

```
UNIVERSALPOSTAL UNION - International Bureau Circular<br />
    By: K.J.S. McKeown
```

please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Don't parse HTML with RegExp. Coldfusion should have some XML processing/parsing libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the regular expression function like this:

```
REMatch("(?s)<em>.*?</em>", html)
```

See also: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=regexp_01.html

- The (?s) sets the mode to single line, so that the input text is interpreted as one line even if it contains line feeds. <s>This is probably the default (I'm not sure) so it can be omitted.</s> As Peter pointed out in a comment, this is not the default and therefore must be set.
- The `.*?` matches all characters inbetween `<em>` and `</em>`. The questionmark after the multiplier makes it "non-greedy", so that as few as possible characters are matched. This is needed in case the input html contains something like `<em>foo</em><em>bar</em>` where otherwise only the outermost `<em></em>` tags are considered.
- The returned array contains all matches found, i.e. all texts including html that was in `<em>` tags.

Note that this could fail for circumstances where `</em>` also occurs as attribute text and is incorrectly not html-encoded, for example: `<em><a title="Help for </em> tag">click</a></em>` or in other rare circumstances (e.g. javascript script tags etc.). A regex cannot replace a full HTML/XML parser and if you need 100% accurateness, you should consider using one: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_t-z_23.html

Comment: XmlParse isn't a HTML parser (it's an XML Parser), so would only work on XHTML, and it requires long-winded DOM-walking that makes it a pain to use. See my answer for jSoup example, which is both a HTML parser and uses selectors to make it easy to use.

Comment: btw `(?s)` is _not_ the default for CF's regex engine (Apache ORO), and I haven't yet encountered a regex library where it is on by default?

Comment: Finally, if using regex for a task like this, it's more efficient to change the `.*?` to `(?:[^<]+|<?(!/em>))*?` so it only has to check for the `</em>` when it actually finds a `<` character, rather than checking at every match - which is what the `.*?` will be doing!

Answer (score 2):

If your input is exactly in the format given above, you don't even need regex - just strip the outer tags:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="Input">[text from above]</cfsavecontent>

<cfset Output = mid( Input, 4 , len(Input) - 9 />
```

If your input is more than this (i.e. a significant piece of HTML, or a full HTML document), regex is still not the ideal tool - instead, **you should be using a HTML parser**, such as [JSoup](http://jsoup.org):

```
<cfset jsoup = createObject('java','org.jsoup.Jsoup') />

<cfset Output = jsoup.parse(Input).select('em').html() />
```

(With CF8, this code requires placing the jsoup JAR file in CF's lib directory, or using a tool such as [JavaLoader](http://javaloader.riaforge.org/).)

Comment: if your full string is like what you posted you could also use REReplace and replace <em> and </em> with an empty string or use 2 replacenocase one for the start and end tags.  This wouldn't work if your string had html / text outside of the em tags that you needed to remove.

Comment: Using `rereplace` would be _much_ slower than doing `mid`. If there is text before the first em, the mid solution can be adapted to use find instead of the hardcoded 4.

Comment: I haven't tested the efficiency of rereplace but if it's a hog then no I wouldn't use it.

Comment: It's not just rereplace - the way regex works is to basically to walk each character one at a time. Using left/right/mid functions can simply modify the contents of the string without walking through all the characters.

Comment: tested all 3 and even using find with your mid solution was much more efficient than 2 replaces or reReplace.  replace x2 is about 10 times slower than find+mid.  replace x2 took about half a second to run.  reReplace took just over a second to complete so twice as slow as 2 replacees. Tested running each 100000 times. <3 saving milliseconds.

Comment: Yep, sometimes milliseconds are important, other times it's just over-optimisation and less-readable code. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery you can do this also pretty easily.

```
$("em").html();
```

Will return all html between the em tags.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PE2bd/)

Comment: Sam didn't specify what he needed to do with the contents, but ColdFusion processes before JavaScript. That may not work since it requires the page to have loaded already.

Comment: phantom42, the point you make is valid, but saying "ColdFusion processes before JavaScript" is misleading. They process in completely different places. CF is server-side. JS is client-side. There's also no guarantee/requirement for CF to load a page in a browser (the above may well be in a scheduled task, an event gateway, or even for sending in an email).

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove any text that was to follow after a partiucular  tag . Now the HTML content was getting generated dynamically from a database that cater to 5 different langauges. so I only had the div tag to help me. I am not sure why REMatch("(?s).*?", html) did not work for me. However Ben helped me here (http://www.bennadel.com/blog/769-Learning-ColdFusion-8-REMatch-For-Regular-Expression-Matching.htm). My code looks like tghis:

```
<cfset extContentArr = REMatch("(?i)<div class=""inlineBlock"" style=""margin-right:30px;"">.+?</div>",qry_getContent.colval) />
<cfif !ArrayIsEmpty(extContentArr)>
  Loop the array and do whatever you need with the extract , I just deleted them.
</cfif>
```